# Android :Video encoder

Tags: android

I am working in android. I designed a video player in my application. Most of videos are playing successfully but in some videos i face problem. This error is occurred when i tried to run videos **"sorry this video cannot be played"**

This is information about my video

```
General

Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 1 133 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-03-07 07:36:33
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-03-07 07:36:33

Video
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 2 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 29s 920ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 000 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 2 212 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.130
Stream size                              : 3.64 MiB (89%)
```

I searched for this on google then i found this is related to format of video. Some one suggest **ffmpeg** and **mencoder** etc but all these things related to command line.

I want to know that is there any way to write code  to encode that video so android default player can play it successfully.

If necessary then i can upload that video.

Please suggest me what should i do for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey resolved my problem myself. This is related to format of my video which is H.264.

I just download jar file from this http://vov.io/vitamio/ link.

Add this jar file into my libraries of my application and use VideoView of this library in place of existing one.

Now its working fine.

Thanks alot who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide more information about video file. you can use [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en). h264 profile & level.

Comment: @Galvin sir please see my updated question. And thank you so much to provide me this software...

Comment: @PushpendraKuntal refer to android developer site(http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), AVC Baseline Profile (BP) is guaranteed to be supported. your stream is AVC High Profile, so it depends on the hardware decoder implementation, but not guaranteed.